# Turn Off Unjailbroken iOS Device From PC

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

Is there a way to turn off a unjailbroken device from the PC? If it was jailbroken I could just SSH into it and turn it off.

Can I boot with the help of a ramdisk and then shut it down? http://msftguy.blogspot.com/2010/11/booting-ssh-ramdisk-on-new-devices.html

Comment: ...except insofar as they interface with your computer. Someone needs a refresher lesson about the FAQ. This question is not off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Apple doesn't let developers make programs like that, so you would need to jailbreak it. Why do you need to turn it off from the PC instead of the iDevice, just out of curiousity?

Comment: I see... I haven't turned OFF an iDevice for ages, so I don't know how speedy it is anymore. Wish there was a non-jailbroken solution for you, but because of Apple's developer's license, developers aren't ALLOWED to make an app that interfaces that closely with the device

Comment: There may be, but I don't know of one. I know with my iPhone 3GS running 5.0.1, when it crashes it just goes back to the springboard (aka the Home Screen). It doesn't actually shut down the phone

Comment: Once you jailbreak, you avoid Apple's restrictions. You can theoretically do anything you want once it's jailbroken. I'm sure there would be an app to do it, or if you enable SSH, you could issue the `shutdown -s now` command (or whatever the Linux command is)

Comment: redsn0w doesn't "shutdown" the phone, it reboots it

Comment: You can jailbreak an iOS 5 iPad 2....

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it is possible without any 3rd party apps installed, from experience with my iPhone there is no way to interface with your device without a program being installed on the device its self. Check the iOS App Store for apps, I've seen apps for remote media control so you might find what you are looking for.